# Find and replace the parameter of MediaWiki template

Tags: python, regex

I am creating a small script to replace the parameter of MediaWiki Template. There are two types of MediaWiki Template form:

**First** (inline):

```
{{Infobox|name = ABC |work = ABC |year = 1021 }}
```

**Second** (non-inline):

```
{{Infobox
|name = ABC
|work = ABC
|year = 1021
}}
```

Now I want to replace the name with CBA:

```
{{Infobox
|name = CBA
|work = ABC
|year = 1021
}}
```

I have three variables in the Python script:

```
param = sheet.cell_value(i + 1, 1)
value = sheet.cell_value(i + 1, 2)
template = sheet.cell_value(i + 1, 3)
```

Here `template = Infobox`, `param = name`, `value= CBA`

I did some searches on Google and found that it will be done by regex. Let store the template content in the text variable. So How we find and replace it?

Please keep in mind that MediaWiki Template may be in both forms (inline or non-inline). and it should not replace the same values of other parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding the significance of `sheet.cell_value`. Can you post a [mcve] showing this code? How is this MediaWiki template represented in the program? Is it a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps:

```
msg = re.sub(r"^(.*name\s*=\s*)[A-Za-z0-9]+(.*)$", r"\1CBA\2", msg, flags=re.S)
```

Explanation:

The Code replaces the content in **msg** with "(regex match group)CBA(regex match group)"

Here is my test-case:

```
import re

pattern = r"name\s*=\s*([A-Za-z0-9]+)"

msg = '{{Infobox|name = ABC |work = ABC |year = 1021 }}'

print(msg)

msg_long = '{{Infobox \
|name = CBA \
|work = ABC \
|year = 1021 \
}}'

msg = re.sub(r"^(.*name\s*=\s*)[A-Za-z0-9]+(.*)$", r"\1CBA\2", msg, flags=re.S)

print(msg)

print(msg_long)

msg_long = re.sub(r"^(.*name\s*=\s*)[A-Za-z0-9]+(.*)$", r"\1CBA\2", msg_long, flags=re.S)

print(msg_long)
```